# Include pdf links in sp list

Tags: list, pdf

SP 2013:  Want to create a list to remind users to review documents.  Need to include links to the documents in the list view as a column

Thanks.

Comment: Use lookup column to that particular library

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the PDF files are saved in SharePoint, and that users have access to both the libraries where the files are housed and your list.  To create links you can:

1. Use a hyperlink column.  You may run into URL length issue.
2. Use a lookup coulmn to associate reminder list items with the files in your list.  I suggest using this method only if files are in one library, and if the Title coulmn for PDFs is not empty and matches the Name.
3. Use a MLT column set to Enhanced Rich Text.  This may be the best option as you won't run into URL length issues and you can set the link to open in a new browser tab.